# Child divs with equal height and wrapping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a parent div with seven or more child divs within. I need to display 4 child divs across... the rest will wrap in subsequent rows of four divs each. I need the child divs to all have equal height, relative to the other three child divs that share the same row. The parent div is responsive as well, so it may end up displaying rows of 2 child divs across when the viewport is smaller.

display:inline-block does not solve this issue (unequal child div heights), and display:table-cell does not allow the child divs to wrap into subsequent rows. How can I accomplish my objectives?

Here is a very basic jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hockey2112/3r2pL25v/

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. This div has a little more information in it, and therefore it will be taller than the other divs.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="tablecell">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>


.table {font-size: 9px;}

.tablecell {display: inline-block;
width: 23%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; vertical-align: top;}
```

Comment: You should use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: That worked perfectly! Here's the updated jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hockey2112/vbubpha4/. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend my comment regarding the usage of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

With flexbox, aligning the height of the elements along the cross-axis is done automatically, since the default value of `justify-content` is `stretch`.

All you have to do, is to set `display: flex;` on the container element. You may also want to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` in order for the child elements to wrap into multiple rows.

Also, the default `flex-direction` is `row`, so you don't need to specify that.

To sum up, you need to use the following CSS style:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 0 23%; /* grow = 1, shrink = 0, basis = 23% */
}
```